# Poor Graphical Performance on Ubuntu 20.04 - Razer Blade Stealth 13" (2017) Intel 7500U

Tags: intel-graphics, 20.04

I hope you are all safe amidst the crisis...

So, I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Razer Blade Stealth 13" (2017) - Intel 7500U and it has been certainly not a good experience with the graphics. Gnome feels so laggy when I navigate anything and everything. Just to be clear, I was not having any mediocre graphical performance whatsoever on Windows 10 as it has more than capable hardware to do simple compositing. I'd be really happy if someone would guide me.

Thanks a bunch...

### What I have tried (without luck):

- Disabled all Gnome extensions.
- Wayland
- Being connected to a laptop charger.
- No power-saving software like `tlp` or `powertop` running.
- Booting with stock Ubuntu kernel command-line parameters.

### Specs (`inxi -Fxxxzc0`)

```
System:    Kernel: 5.4.0-29-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: gcc v: 9.3.0 Desktop: Gnome 3.36.1 wm: gnome-shell 
           dm: GDM3 3.34.1 Distro: Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Razer product: Blade Stealth v: 3.06 serial: <filter> Chassis: type: 9 serial: N/A 
           Mobo: Razer model: Blade Stealth serial: N/A UEFI: Razer v: 1.51 date: 05/21/2019 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 42.5 Wh condition: 50.6/53.8 Wh (94%) volts: 12.3/11.6 model: Razer Razer Blade Stealth 
           type: Unknown serial: <filter> status: Discharging 
CPU:       Topology: Dual Core model: Intel Core i7-7500U bits: 64 type: MT MCP arch: Amber Lake rev: 9 L1 cache: 128 KiB 
           L2 cache: 4096 KiB L3 cache: 4096 KiB 
           flags: avx avx2 lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx bogomips: 23199 
           Speed: 800 MHz min/max: 400/3500 MHz Core speeds (MHz): 1: 800 2: 800 3: 800 4: 800 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 620 vendor: Razer USA driver: i915 v: kernel bus ID: 00:02.0 chip ID: 8086:5916 
           Display: server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: i915 compositor: gnome-shell resolution: 3200x1800~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 620 (KBL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 20.0.4 direct render: Yes 
Audio:     Device-1: Intel Sunrise Point-LP HD Audio vendor: Razer USA driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel bus ID: 00:1f.3 
           chip ID: 8086:9d71 
           Sound Server: ALSA v: k5.4.0-29-generic 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 driver: iwlwifi v: kernel port: f040 bus ID: 01:00.0 chip ID: 8086:2723 
           IF: wlp1s0 state: up mac: <filter> 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 238.47 GiB used: 172.83 GiB (72.5%) 
           ID-1: /dev/nvme0n1 vendor: Samsung model: MZVLV256HCHP-00000 size: 238.47 GiB speed: 31.6 Gb/s lanes: 4 
           serial: <filter> rev: BXV7000Q scheme: GPT 
Partition: ID-1: / size: 54.54 GiB used: 15.57 GiB (28.5%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/nvme0n1p6 
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 50.0 C mobo: 29.8 C 
           Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A 
Info:      Processes: 277 Uptime: 11h 17m Memory: 15.53 GiB used: 3.08 GiB (19.8%) Init: systemd v: 245 runlevel: 5 Compilers: 
           gcc: 9.3.0 alt: 9 Shell: bash (sudo) v: 5.0.16 running in: gnome-terminal inxi: 3.0.38
```

### Other Logs

- [Relevant /var/log/kern.log](https://pastebin.com/z7GxPBdM)
- [dmesg log](https://pastebin.com/Vr9hvjgP)
- [systemd-analyze plot](https://siasky.net/XADMXU644oeOqK97lp_S9ngWgSZ08TbAxfOuuwfH9kHFSw)

Comment: `dpkg -l | grep xserver-xorg-video-intel` please.

Comment: `ii  xserver-xorg-video-intel                   2:2.99.917+git20200226-1                   amd64        X.Org X server -- Intel i8xx, i9xx display driver`

Comment: remove his package for test purpose. this was the fix for me. If something goes bad you can install the package again.